# Is there a tool can identify a site login page's authentication (or anti spider) method fast and give result?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-crawler

I'm writing a multi-site spider. Most of those sites are using anti-spider methods or complex authentication process.
Is there a tool or browser-extension that can record all network requests between before-login-page and after-login-page and identify key requests automaticly? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because every site's login method is different and many login params is dynamic generated, so even if you record all requests. In most cases, it may be useless.